# VPN Client while DD-WRT is in Router operating mode (WAP)

Tags: dd-wrt

This might be a dumb question, but is it possible to have a VPN client working with DD-WRT when the hardware (asus rt-n16) is set to router mode (WAP)?

Or must the DD-WRT be set to act as a gateway?

I have my DD-WRT cascaded to my regular DSL+Wifi+Phone router. Everything works but VPN. Unfortunately I cannot enable a bridge mode on my router (Zyxel P-2602HWN). I think my ISP blocked this out, god forbid you try to use anything but their crappy wifi which drops every 5 minutes.